# winreg - SaveKey() returns WinError 1314 and creates empty file

Tags: python, registry, winreg

I don't know the reason of this behavior, but **while running `winreg`'s `SaveKey` function on Python 3.11** an empty file is written while returning WinError 1314 (*A required privilege is not held by the client.*)

I am running shell as an administrator (code below) and I do not understand why it fails. Can somebody help me to fix this?

---

```py
>>> import winreg
>>> import ctypes
>>>
>>> # UAC activated
>>> ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
True
>>>
>>> location = r"C:\Users\Key.reg"
>>>
>>> with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_USERS, ".DEFAULT", access = winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as key:
...     winreg.SaveKey(key, location)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 1314] A required privilege is not held by the client.
>>>
>>> open(location).read()
''
>>>
```